# How to debug the PVclaims pending issue in Openshift Container Platform 3.4

Tags: openshift, persistent

I'm trying to mount NFS storage to my container, reference in here: https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/dev_guide/persistent_volumes.html 
My pvc can't bound to the pv, I don't know how to debug on it? 
Could anyone can give some advice.

```
[root@ocp-master01 smokeping]# oc get pv
NAME              CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   RECLAIMPOLICY   STATUS      CLAIM                    REASON    AGE
registry-volume   5Gi        RWX           Retain          Bound       default/registry-claim             13d
smokeping-conf    50Gi       RWO,RWX       Recycle         Available   network/smokeping                  3h
[root@ocp-master01 smokeping]# oc get pvc
NAME             STATUS    VOLUME    CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   AGE
smokeping-conf   Pending                                      3h


[root@ocp-master01 smokeping]# oc describe pv/smokeping-conf
Name:       smokeping-conf
Labels:     <none>
StorageClass:   
Status:     Available
Claim:      network/smokeping
Reclaim Policy: Recycle
Access Modes:   RWO,RWX
Capacity:   50Gi
Message:    
Source:
    Type:   NFS (an NFS mount that lasts the lifetime of a pod)
    Server: nfs.com.cn
    Path:   /ifs/linuxsys/ocp/smokeping
    ReadOnly:   false
No events.

# oc describe pvc/smokeping-conf
Name:       smokeping-conf
Namespace:  network
StorageClass:   
Status:     Pending
Volume:     
Labels:     <none>
Capacity:   
Access Modes:   
No events.
```

Here is my PVC config file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2017-06-19T02:46:28Z
  name: smokeping-conf
  namespace: network
  resourceVersion: "1541191"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/network/persistentvolumeclaims/smokeping-conf
  uid: 7e48452b-5499-11e7-bb2a-001a4a160162
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
status:
  phase: Pending
```

Comment: Hi, From your output i see you didn't specified any spec.accessModes or spec.resources.requests.storage in your PVC. Maybe you should try to fill these fields.

Comment: I did. I should print out my pvc conf file to here:
`apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2017-06-19T02:46:28Z
  name: smokeping-conf
  namespace: network
  resourceVersion: "1541191"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/network/persistentvolumeclaims/smokeping-conf
  uid: 7e48452b-5499-11e7-bb2a-001a4a160162
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 50Gi
status:
  phase: Pending`

Comment: Please add your conf file to your question. It's too hard to read in the comments.

Comment: I just updated my PVC config file to my question, please kindly check.

Comment: what's the output of `oc get pv`?

Comment: I changed the name to "name: smokeping" in my PVC config file. Now the problem is solved. In the PVC config file, it has to mount the claim name not metadata name. Thanks for all your help here.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to specify exact claim for pv

```
spec:
  claimRef:
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
    name: <claim_name>
    namespace: <namespace>
```

And for claim

```
spec:
  volumeName: <volume_name>
```